# Ignore TMUX prefix?

Tags: linux, bash, tmux

I have my tmux prefix key bound to ` via

```
set -g prefix `
```

I have been using this for a while and like it.

The problem is, on rare occasions I actually need the ` accent. If I am in vim this is not a big deal as I can use digraphs (C-k '!) but occasionally I need it on the command line.

Is there a way I can temporarily disable the my prefix key to allow this?

Answer (score 2):

To send the prefix key to an underlying program, just type it twice. For example, if you use default prefix key <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd><kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>b</kbd>. In your particular case this means hit <kbd>`</kbd> twice.